# Overloading protected and private methods in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, overloading

In Java I have the following piece of code:

```
protected int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
private int add(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
```

I do realise that you can achieve the above in Ruby using the `*args` parameter. But then you won't be able to differentiate between the **private** and **protected** versions of that method. Is there any way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of private and protected methods in Ruby is somewhat different than it is in languages like Java (well, not so much public, that's very similar :)). In Java if a method is declared private, it can only be accessed from other methods in the same class. When a method is declared protected it can be accessed by other classes in the same package as well as by subclasses of its class in a different package

```
   class A
     def main_method
       method1
     end

     private
      def method1
       puts "hello from #{self.class}"
      end
   end

   class B < A
    def main_method
     method1
    end
   end

   A.new.main_method
   B.new.main_method


  Print: =
  hello from A
  hello from B
```

try to use an explicit receiver, even if the receiver is "self", the method call will fail e.g.

```
class C < A
  def main_method
   self.method1
  end
end

C.new.main_method
```

Gives in `main_method': private method`method1' called for # (NoMethodError)

```
class A
  def main_method
    method1
  end

  protected
   def method1
    puts "hello from #{self.class}"
   end
end

class B < A
 def main_method
  method1
 end
end

class C < A
 def main_method
  self.method1
 end
end
```

Print
hello from A
hello from B
hello from C

You can read more about implicit receiver to understand it.

Comment: Do you mean that in your second snippet of code, if you try and run it, the error only triggers at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can do this. There is no overloading in Ruby. There aren't private and protected version**s** (plural). There is only one single method. That single method can be protected or it can be private but not both.